# Ubuntu 16.04 Login loop Issue

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

Though this is a common problem, none of the online solutions worked for me.

**What I did:**

1. Fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 (System76 Oryx Pro)
2. Installed NVIDIA drivers (Tried, 390, 387, 384, system76-default drivers). I tried the `.run` file as well as the `apt-get install nvidia-current` (In separate installation attempts)
3. I installed the driver virtually after disabling lightdm. After installation I login and it fails.

**List of things I tried that didn't work:**

1. Moved `.Xauthority` to `.Xauthority.bak` and logging in..
2. Created a blacklist file with the content, `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf`, with the content : `blacklist nouveau options nouveau modeset=0`
3. Killed Xserver before installing NVIDIA
4. `lsmod | grep nvidia` , doesn't show nouveau, which means that nouveau isn't running causing a conflict.
5. I updated the linux kernel image to the latest (4.13.0-45-generic). I also tried an older 4.4.0-128-generic image. Both didn't work
6. Uninstalled lightdm, and installed gdm, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with login loop for 3 days on Ubuntu 16.04 I changed to Ubuntu 17.10 and all issues related to login loop have gone. So I highly recommend to uninstall your current version and install Ubuntu 17.10.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this as a last resort if nothing else works. Thanks!